# Testing if a click is in a div and all its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing an issue about this.

```
<div id="1">
    <div id="2">
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        <div id="4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="others_div">
</div>
```

I want to add the class "hidden" to "1" when I click on something which is not "1" nor one of its children.

Now I am using this but I have a lack of imagination for solving this issue...

```
document.onclick = function(e)
{
    if(e.target.id!="1")
    {
        $("#1").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: $( this).on( "click", "div", function(e) {
  if(e.target.id != "1")
    {
        $("#1").addClass("hidden");
    }
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to avoid `e.stopPropagation()` *(maybe you want that event to bubble up to some other ancestor*) You can check if it is not clicked on `#1` nor on it's children like this:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {

     if (!((e.target.id== "1") || $(e.target).closest('#1').length)) {
       $("#1").addClass("hidden");
     }    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery check like the following one to check if the current element is your `1` element or traverse the DOM to see if the current target is contained within an element with an ID of `1` :

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          // Trigger this when something is clicked
          $(document).click(function(e){
              // Toggle the hidden class based on if the current element is 1
              // or if it is contained in an element with ID of 1
              $("#1").toggleClass('hidden',!((e.target.id== "1") || $(e.target).closest('#1').length))
          });
      });
</script>
```

Generally, you should [avoid using ID attributes that only consists of numbers as they are not valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) (ID attributes must begin with a letter). Ignoring this could result in some issues with regards to CSS or jQuery selection.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$('body').on( "click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.id !== "1")
    {
        $("#1").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```js
// taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

$('html').click(function() {
 //Hide the menus if visible
  alert('hide');
});

$('#one').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div#one {
  background: yellow;
}

div#others_div {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one">
  div one
  <div id="2">
    div two
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    div three
    <div id="4">
      div four
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="others_div">
  other div
</div>
```